# With substitution given integrate w.r.t.x

Tags: integration

I have the question "Using the substitution given, integrate with respect to $x$"

Here is my working:

[image]

I understand everything expect for the bit after the word "hence".

If $6x^2$ cancels out, then where does the $\frac 16$ come from ?

Comment: Wait, didn't *you* write those equations? You write "Here is my working"?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say I used the solutions to help with my working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral after the word hence is incorrect. It should read
$$
\int x^2 U^5 \frac{1}{6x^2} du
$$
which should make it clear where the 1/6 comes from. In fact, I'm not sure why there was a $6x^2$ instead of an $x^2$ in that integral in the first place.